# How do I increase the resolution of Matplotlib plots in Jupyter Book?

Tags: jupyterbook

I typically use `plt.rcParams['figure.dpi'] = 300` to increase the resolution of Matplotlib plots in my Jupyter notebooks.
However, this setting does not seem to work with Jupyter Books.
Here are reproducible steps:

1. Create a Jupyter Book template with `jupyter-book create mynewbook`
2. To `mynewbook/notebooks.ipynb`, add a code cell with `rcParams['figure.dpi'] = 600` just before the plot
3. Build this Jupyter Book with `jupyter-book build --builder pdflatex mynewbook`

The figure in `notebooks.ipynb` remains the default resolution (72 dpi?) instead of 600 dpi, even though the in-notebook resolution is 600 dpi. How can I increase the resolution of Matplotlib (and seaborn) plots in Jupyter Books?

Answer (score 0):

In this [post](https://blakeaw.github.io/2020-05-25-improve-matplotlib-notebook-inline-res/) the author proposes to increase the resolution:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot
pyplot.rcParams['figure.dpi'] = 600
pyplot.rcParams['savefig.dpi'] = 600
```

This works for me.

Comment: Thanks! I think I am following his advice via my `rcParams['figure.dpi'] = 600` (the Jupyter Book template imports `rcParams` without the `plt` prefix). I think the difference between my question and his post is that I am building a Jupyter Book while the linked post is about single Jupyter Notebooks.